# c++11 std::array of std::atomic zero initialization failure to compile?

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++

Compiling the below with zero-initialized atomics under both g++ 4.7 and g++ 4.8.2 takes hours.   Default-initialized atomics and zero-initialized non-atomic compile immediately.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //std::array<std::atomic<int>, 1000000>  arr;         // default initialization (i.e., random data) = FAST

    //std::array<int, 1000000>  arr={{}};     // zero init non-atomic = FAST

    //std::array<std::atomic<int>, 1000000>  arr{{}};   // zero initialization = FOREVER

    //std::array<std::atomic<int>, 1000000>  arr={{}};     // zero init via assignment = FOREVER

    std::array<std::atomic<int>, 1000000>  arr{};   // zero initialization = FOREVER

    std::cerr << "sum = " << std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0) << std::endl;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++11 array.cpp`

Is the only option to memset the array manually?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You forgot to post a question.

Comment: [Clang accepts all of these forms at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/955bec21c9307856) Looks like a gcc issue.

Comment: Thanks - default-initialized + std::fill(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0) compiles quickly and produces expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking into GCC with GDB when it's busy shows that it's stuck in [`split_nonconstant_init_1`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/cp/typeck2.c?revision=205262&view=markup), where the code contains a comment:

> FIXME: Ordered removal is O(1) so the whole function is worst-case quadratic.

(O(1) is probably a typo, the function is O(N), and the comment wouldn't make sense if it's O(1).)

So, yes, this is a compiler bug, and one that's already known. However, I haven't checked the GCC bugzilla to see if they have a simple testcase already; if they don't, you may want to report it.

As for what you can do now, the comments on your question show that you already have a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thanks - gcc bug submitted.